# Tabular Model: Import data in compatibility 1400

Tags: visual-studio-2017, azure-sql-database, ssas-tabular, azure-analysis-services

Hope you are doing well.
I really need your help.

I am trying to create a tabular model in Azure  analysis service with SSDT 2017.
Data is in Azure SQL Server.
I chose the compatibility 1400 and I saw the database objets.

But  when I try to import data from the database I have an error "error ole dB".
[image]

I have also created a model with compatibility 1200. And all runs well with this compatibility.

Do you have any Idea on how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Azure SQL database compatibility level.
In SSMS, right-click the database name > Properties > Compatibility Level.

[image]

For more details, please reference: [Compatibility level for Analysis Services tabular models](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/tabular-models/compatibility-level-for-tabular-models-in-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017).

Set the compatibility level 140 and try again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But it doesn't work for me. But Azure Sql Qerver is already in Compatibity 140.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the latest version of SSDT 2017 (15.9.0). Download and install from [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2052454). Before installing SSDT for Visual Studio 2017 (15.9.0), uninstall Analysis Services Projects and Reporting Services Projects extensions, and close all VS instances.

Another possible solution is to try SSDT 2019. If you do not have VS 2019 download and install the [Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/?utm_medium=microsoft&utm_source=learn.microsoft.com&utm_content=sqlssdt) version, then install the Analysis Services extension.

Comment: Hello Thank you for your help . I am now using Vistual Studio  Entreprise 2017 . Version 15.9.7. I will try to install Visual Studio 2019. Thank you

Comment: Installing Visual Studio  doesn't solve my issue. I have the same error. "Ole Db or ODBC error"  :-(

Comment: I will investigate and get help on this one.